# How to detect if a GET request is from a browser or not

Tags: python, api, curl, user-agent

I'm looking for a way to show html to a user if they call from a browser or just give them the API response in JSON if the call is made from an application, terminal with curl or generally any other way.

I know a number of APIs do this and I believe Django's REST framework does this.

I've been able to fool a number of those APIs by passing in my browser's useragent to curl so I know this is done using useragents, but how do I implement this? To cover every single possible or most useragents out there.

There has to be a file/database or a regex, so that I don't have to worry about updating my useragent lists every few months, and worrying that my users on the latest browsers might not be able to access my website.

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php Does this help?

Comment: Need run some code on client side, otherwise `no way !`, what is differences `robot vs human` ?

Comment: @reevkandari that's a really large list, I'm thinking I could just do if 'Chrome' in useragent or something, that's looking like the best approach

Comment: @Jonathan so whats the big deal make an python list, loop through it.The more the merrier

Comment: @reevkandari performance :) The API as is, is very minimal and very fast, I'm worried reading that into memory (needs to be done everytime on lambda) will bump up the response times, also are you aware of any means to export the lists from the site?

Comment: sorry for delay from my end..
https://pastebin.com/NBh4GKir 
i have converted it into lsv, you can now convert them to lists and loop..

Comment: Thanks, I think that could be an answer, if you'd post it as such, I'll accept it

Comment: As a matter of principle: Don't do that. This seems like a good idea, but it's actually a bad one. URLs designate resources. A resource can be JSON, or HTML, or anything. But the URL that fetches the JSON should not be the same URL that fetches the HTML. Add a `format` parameter. Make it explicit. Forget user agent sniffing, you are making things harder to test, harder to reproduce and - ultimately, harder to maintain. You'd need to keep your "whitelist" up to date, you'd need to document this stuff, and you *will* create unnecessary edge cases. Just don't.

Comment: @Tomalak I am trying to do something similar to the transfer.sh case of displaying a browser preview version, and I don't think it is a bad idea. In that case, it only uses the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @reevkandari's pastebin, the following Python code works very well in production for me

```
browser_useragents = ["ABrowse", "Acoo Browser", "America Online Browser", "AmigaVoyager", "AOL", "Arora", "Avant Browser", "Beonex", "BonEcho", "Browzar", "Camino", "Charon", "Cheshire", "Chimera", "Chrome", "ChromePlus", "Classilla", "CometBird", "Comodo_Dragon", "Conkeror", "Crazy Browser", "Cyberdog", "Deepnet Explorer", "DeskBrowse", "Dillo", "Dooble", "Edge", "Element Browser", "Elinks", "Enigma Browser", "EnigmaFox", "Epiphany", "Escape", "Firebird", "Firefox", "Fireweb Navigator", "Flock", "Fluid", "Galaxy", "Galeon", "GranParadiso", "GreenBrowser", "Hana", "HotJava", "IBM WebExplorer", "IBrowse", "iCab", "Iceape", "IceCat", "Iceweasel", "iNet Browser", "Internet Explorer", "iRider", "Iron", "K-Meleon", "K-Ninja", "Kapiko", "Kazehakase", "Kindle Browser", "KKman", "KMLite", "Konqueror", "LeechCraft", "Links", "Lobo", "lolifox", "Lorentz", "Lunascape", "Lynx", "Madfox", "Maxthon", "Midori", "Minefield", "Mozilla", "myibrow", "MyIE2", "Namoroka", "Navscape", "NCSA_Mosaic", "NetNewsWire", "NetPositive", "Netscape", "NetSurf", "OmniWeb", "Opera", "Orca", "Oregano", "osb-browser", "Palemoon", "Phoenix", "Pogo", "Prism", "QtWeb Internet Browser", "Rekonq", "retawq", "RockMelt", "Safari", "SeaMonkey", "Shiira", "Shiretoko", "Sleipnir", "SlimBrowser", "Stainless", "Sundance", "Sunrise", "surf", "Sylera", "Tencent Traveler", "TenFourFox", "theWorld Browser", "uzbl", "Vimprobable", "Vonkeror", "w3m", "WeltweitimnetzBrowser", "WorldWideWeb", "Wyzo", "Android Webkit Browser", "BlackBerry", "Blazer", "Bolt", "Browser for S60", "Doris", "Dorothy", "Fennec", "Go Browser", "IE Mobile", "Iris", "Maemo Browser", "MIB", "Minimo", "NetFront", "Opera Mini", "Opera Mobile", "SEMC-Browser", "Skyfire", "TeaShark", "Teleca-Obigo", "uZard Web", "Thunderbird", "AbiLogicBot", "Link Valet", "Link Validity Check", "LinkExaminer", "LinksManager.com_bot", "Mojoo Robot", "Notifixious", "online link validator", "Ploetz + Zeller", "Reciprocal Link System PRO", "REL Link Checker Lite", "SiteBar", "Vivante Link Checker", "W3C-checklink", "Xenu Link Sleuth", "EmailSiphon", "CSE HTML Validator", "CSSCheck", "Cynthia", "HTMLParser", "P3P Validator", "W3C_CSS_Validator_JFouffa", "W3C_Validator", "WDG_Validator", "Awasu", "Bloglines", "everyfeed-spider", "FeedFetcher-Google", "GreatNews", "Gregarius", "MagpieRSS", "NFReader", "UniversalFeedParser", "!Susie", "Amaya", "Cocoal.icio.us", "DomainsDB.net MetaCrawler", "gPodder", "GSiteCrawler", "iTunes", "lftp", "MetaURI", "MT-NewsWatcher", "Nitro PDF", "Snoopy", "URD-MAGPIE", "WebCapture", "Windows-Media-Player"]
    if any(browser_useragent in request['userAgent'] for browser_useragent in browser_useragents):
        return "<html>Website HTML</html>"
else:
    return api JSON or XML
```

Comment: This is a *really* bad idea, see my other comment for an explanation. Not everything that can be done should be done. This is one of those things.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a few years old, but since I stumbled upon it...

**tldr;** Do not use the user agent to determine the return format unless absolutely necessary.  Use the `Accept` header or (less ideal) use a separate endpoint/URL.

The standard and most future-proof way to set the desired return format for a specific endpoint is to use the `Accept` header.  `Accept` is explicitly designed to allow the client to state what response format they would like returned.  The value will be a standard MIME type.

Web browsers, by default, will send `text/html` as the value of the `Accept` header.  Most Javascript libraries and frontend frameworks will send `application/json`, but this can usually be explicitly set to something else (e.g. `text/xml`) if needed.  All mobile app frameworks and HTTP client libraries that I am aware of have the ability to set this header if needed.

There are two big problems with trying to use user agent for simply determining the response format:

1. *The list will be massive.*  You will need to account for every possible client which needs to be supported today.  If this endpoint is used internally, this may not be an immediate problem as you ***might*** be able to enforce which user agents you will accept (may cause its own set of problems in the future, e.g. forcing your users to a specific version of Internet Explorer indefinitely) which will help keep this list small. If this endpoint is to be exposed externally, you will almost certainly miss something you badly need to accept.
2. *The list will change.*  You will need to account for every possible client which needs to be supported tomorrow, next week, next year, and in five years.  This becomes a self-induced maintenance headache.

Two notes regarding `Accept`:

1. Please read up on how to use the `Accept` header before attempting to implement against it.  Here is an actual example from this website: `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9`.  Given this, I would return back HTML.
2. The value of the header can be `*/*`, which basically just says "whatever" or "I don't care".  At that point, the server is allowed to determine the response format.